# What is the repeater argument in pack?

Tags: php, hex, pack

I need to convert a string to hexadecimal. I read about the `pack` function. What is the difference between the following?

```
$hexRepresentation = pack('H','I will be converted to hexa');
```

and

```
$hexRepresentation = pack('H*','I will be converted to hexa');
```

The documentation on the [repeater argument](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) is not very clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

1) If you want to convert string binary to hex - there is a better function for this: [bin2hex](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php)

2) [pack](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) function can convert data **into binary** string. I think you mean - [unpack](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php)

As mentioned in documentation - PHP's pack\unpack functions are a port of Perl's pack\unpack.

Behavior of this function depends on which format you are using.

For the h and H formats pack:

> A * for the repeat count uses all characters of the input field.

You can check perl's documentation [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html)

Example:

```
<?php

$string='I will be converted to hexa';
var_dump(unpack('H10',$string));
//array(1) {
//  [1]=>
//  string(10) "492077696c"
//}
var_dump(unpack('H*',$string));
//array(1) {
//  [1]=>
//  string(54) "492077696c6c20626520636f6e76657274656420746f2068657861"
//}
var_dump(bin2hex($string));
//string(54) "492077696c6c20626520636f6e76657274656420746f2068657861"
```

Also, you can try it yourself here: https://3v4l.org/a4BVi